# error installing module HybridAuth and Drupal 8-10

Tags: php, drupal-8, drupal-modules, hybridauth, drupal-10

i try to install HybridAuth module on Drupal 8 and 10 using composer on ddev but i had errors :
module : https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth
erreor:
ddev composer require 'drupal/hybridauth:^2.16'
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drupal/hybridauth
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires drupal/hybridauth, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
  see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
- It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
Composer [require drupal/hybridauth:^2.16] failed, composer command failed: exit status 2. stderr=

thanks,

I try to change from drupal 10 to drupal 8 with fresh version, and i got the same error

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Did you set any private repository to load the package from? Also, the page you've linked to doesn't even mention `composer require` as the main installation method

Comment: Also, keep in mind that that module hasn't seen a lot of activity in recent years. Are you sure you want to use it?